# Scale proportionally in Adobe apps without shift key?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, scale

I'm using adobe illustrator (and indesign and photoshop) on a surface book windows laptop, which allows you to use the full version of Illustrator on the detached screen, which acts as a tablet although it is running the full apps rather than mobile apps. This is great, except that I can't figure out how to scale proportionally without the keyboard attached (using <kbd>shift</kbd> key). Is there another way to do this? Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply scale using the transform palette and keeping aspect ratio locked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you mean by using the touchpad to type in new values? It doesn't seem to work to use the pen to scale the object keeping the aspect ratio locked, nor am I able to scroll through the values using the up/down arrows because the keyboard is not attached.